# How to determine a vector has its sum equal to zero?

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I have a non-negative matrix **p**, which has has elements that sum to 1 in each row.

How can I find a non-negative vector **x** which has it's sum equals 1, such as:
(**i**-t(**p**))***x** = 0?
(where **i** is diagonal matrix and t(**p**) is the matrix transpose)

Comment: This sounds to me more like a problem in matrix algebra than in programming.  Maybe try asking here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions  Also, I am not sure whether you want the sum of the vector to be 0, from the title, or 1, from the body of the post.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ would also work. (You're looking for an eigenvector of `t(p)` corresponding to the eigenvalue 1, btw)

Comment: I ask this question because i have an exercise in R relative with it

Comment: Normally if you want to know if two things are equal you can use `==`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @user: first write out the matrix algebra equations which solve the problem.  Only then do you start figuring out how to write the R code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

??eigenvector suggests 'base::eigen'.
?eigen also suggests 'svd'.

svd gives you what you want, but will not be scaled correctly.

"Sum equal 1" is just a scale.  Typically eigenvectors are scaled as to have a length of 1 instead.

Edited:

You're looking for a particular vector with sum of 1.  Not just any vector.  You want a vector that is an eigenvector with the eigenvalue of 1.

Once you have such a (nonzero) vector x, any multiple of x will also be an eigenvector.  In particular, the vector x/sum(x) has elements which sum to 1.

Comment: Sorry, the question is: How to determine a vector has its sum equal to one?